# css/bootstrap - how do i keep text from overflowing button?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button group where I would like to keep the text inside the element. I don't write CSS much and would love to solve it using twitter bootstrap

My problem: 
[image]

The buttons are the right size, I'd just like to keep the text inside.

The group is generated using angularjs. I'd like the `<p>` text to stay inside the parent div

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical col-md-3">
    <div class='btn btn-default' ng-repeat="(route_id, route) in routes">
        <h2>{{route.short_name}}</h2>
        <p>{{ route.description }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could try to set `word-wrap: break-word;` to your p element. In that way the word that doesn't fit on the first line goes to the second line beneath it.

Comment: doesn't work. maybe bootstrap is overriding something :/

Answer (score 1):

use :- on your second div

style="overflow:hidden;height:30px;width:30px"

adjust height and width according to your needs the bootstrap class must be over riding the height and width

if above doesnt work try using style="clear:both"

Comment: that chops off the text and makes it all ugly. Don't want that

Comment: then use style="overflow:hidden;height:30px;width:30px" try changing the values of height and width from 30 to any number which fits it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `word-wrap: break-word;` that will help you if you give `overflow:hidden` it will work but it will chop

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, i applied the following css to the button

```
style='display: table;white-space: pre-line;word-break: break-all;'
```

The above `css` rules will keep the button responsive. Thus the text about to be "overflown" would be moved to the next line of the button.